# Trying to Calculate Built-up Class area using ESA LULC

Tags: google-earth-engine, land-cover, land-classification, land-use

I am trying to calculate the Built Up class area but not getting the correct result. I am using ESA 10 Meter LULC.

'''

```
var area = ee.FeatureCollection("users/Muhammad_Waqas/District_Boundary");
var geometry = area.filter(ee.Filter.eq('DISTRICT', 'SHAHDAD KOT'));
var kot = geometry.geometry();
print('District kot Area (Ha)',kot.area().divide(1e6));
Map.centerObject(kot);
Map.addLayer(kot, {color: 'silver'}, 'kot');
var after_end='2021-12-31';
var LC = ee.ImageCollection('ESA/WorldCover/v100')
  .filterDate('2020-01-01',after_end)
  .sort('system:index',false).select("Map")
  .first().clip(area);

//Mask Built UP Area
var urbanmask = LC
  .eq(50);
var urban = LC
  .updateMask(urbanmask);
var urban_area = urban.updateMask(urban);

// Pixel Count
var urban_pixelarea = urban_area.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()); 
print(urban_pixelarea);
var urban_area = urban_pixelarea.multiply(100); 
var area = urban_area.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: kot,
  scale: 10,
  maxPixels: 1e13
  });
var urbanArea= ee.Number(area.get('Map')).divide(10000).round()
print(urbanArea);
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/3cfa678749dca8d9bcdd1b08a6bd480c

Answer (score 1):

You're maksing off everything that isn't class 50, but then you're multiplying that by the pixelArea.
So, instead of this:

```
var urban_pixelarea = urban_area.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea());
```

you probably want this:

```
var urban_pixelarea = urbanmask.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea());
```